# How to display string value on xAxis label in line chart(MP chart 3.0)

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts

In my objective c project I need to Migrating MPChart from 2.2 to 3.0 for supporting my project in Xcode 9.2. but sum code is changed now.

#### view DidLoad

```
xAxis.valueFormatter = self;
```

#### chart update function

```
- (void)setDataCount:(int)count range:(double)range

{
    xVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < dateAll.count; i++)

    {

           [xVals addObject:[dateAll objectAtIndex:i]];

    }

    NSLog(@"xVals  %@",xVals);





    NSMutableArray *yVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrtymHr.count; i++)

    {

            double vals = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[arrtymHr objectAtIndex:i],[arrtymMnt objectAtIndex:i]] doubleValue];

            [yVals addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithX:i y:vals]];

    }

    NSLog(@"yVals  %@",yVals);







    LineChartDataSet *set1 = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals label:@"DataSet 1"];



    set1.axisDependency = AxisDependencyRight;

    [set1 setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:51/255.f green:181/255.f blue:229/255.f alpha:1.f]];

    [set1 setCircleColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    set1.lineWidth = 2.0;

    set1.circleRadius = 3.0;

    set1.fillAlpha = 0.70;

    set1.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51/255.f green:181/255.f blue:229/255.f alpha:1.f];

    set1.highlightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:244/255.f green:117/255.f blue:117/255.f alpha:1.f];

    set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = YES;

    set1.drawFilledEnabled = !set1.isDrawFilledEnabled;





    NSMutableArray *yVals2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < Allpost.count; i++)

    {

          double vals = [[Allpost objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue];

          [yVals2 addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithX:i y:vals]];

    }

    NSLog(@"yVals 2  %@",yVals2);



    LineChartDataSet *set2 = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals2 label:@"DataSet 2"];

    set2.axisDependency = AxisDependencyLeft;

    [set2 setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:245/255.f green:130/255.f blue:32/255.f alpha:1.f]];

    [set2 setCircleColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    set2.lineWidth = 3.0;

    set2.circleRadius = 3.0;

    set2.fillAlpha = 1.0;

    set2.fillColor = UIColor.redColor;

    set2.highlightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:244/255.f green:117/255.f blue:117/255.f alpha:1.f];

    set2.drawCircleHoleEnabled = YES;





    NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [dataSets addObject:set1];

    [dataSets addObject:set2];





    LineChartData *data = [[LineChartData alloc] initWithDataSets:dataSets];

    [data setValueTextColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [data setValueFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.f]];



    _chartView.data = data;



}
```

#### formatter function

```
- (NSString *)stringForValue:(double)value

                        axis:(ChartAxisBase *)axis

{

    return [xVals objectAtIndex:value];

}
```

but the problem is the array only have one value but it displays more than one.

Printed Array

```
xVals  (
    "03/08",
    "03/16",
    "03/16",
    "03/16"
)

yVals  (
    "ChartDataEntry, x: 0.0, y 0.0",
    "ChartDataEntry, x: 1.0, y 0.0",
    "ChartDataEntry, x: 2.0, y 0.0",
    "ChartDataEntry, x: 3.0, y 0.0"
)

yVals 2  (
    "ChartDataEntry, x: 0.0, y 5.5",
    "ChartDataEntry, x: 1.0, y 7.0",
    "ChartDataEntry, x: 2.0, y 7.0",
    "ChartDataEntry, x: 3.0, y 3.0"
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per new Charts update you need to create `ChartDataEntry` in which you can add both **X** & **Y** value and than add it into `LineChartDataSet`

**Please check below code :**

```
//Create values array 
NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Create 
[yValArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
     [values addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithX:idx y:obj];
}];
```

> In above code we are adding index in DataEntry form 0 .... N.

```
//Add dataEntry Object into values array
[values addObject:dataEntry];

//Create DataSet with values array
LineChartDataSet *set1 = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:values label:@"your_label_for_data_set"];

//Add Line Chart Data inro Chart.
LineChartData *data = [[LineChartData alloc] initWithDataSet:set1];

//Set Data to Line Chart
_lineChartTrend.data = data;
```

Now use your Formatter and return value based on index like below

```
- (NSString *)stringForValue:(double)value
                        axis:(ChartAxisBase *)axis
{
    if (yourLineChart.xAxis == axis) {
        return [xValArray objectAtIndex:value];
    }
}
```

Where value is your index which we have added in DataEntry.

By Doing this you will get your X & Y value on your line Chart.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment and Question updation you need to add one more property for your XAxis so that it will not repeat XAxis value and will remain same as per your array, set below code and you will get expected output on your chart.

```
ChartXAxis *xAxis = self.lineChart.xAxis;
xAxis.granularity = 1.0;
```

Try this and let me know is it working or not.

Comment: but we need the string value to display on X axis. It is display now like image shown by adding the value formatter.

Comment: didn't get what you mean by "he array only have one value but it displays more than one." ? please provide more detail

Comment: the xVals is NSMutableArray for x axis, only contain one value ("03/18”). but display more than one see the image of chart attached.

Comment: yes its showing multiple so what you want ? single value ?

Comment: we need to display values in xAxis based on the array.

Comment: can you add your array value and LineChart setup in your question so I can get idea whats going wrong.

Comment: plz see the array values and compare with the updated attached image.

Comment: I have update my answer with one more property please try it once.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
@interface ViewController ()<IChartAxisValueFormatter>
```

viewDidLoad

```
xAxis.axisRange = 1;
xAxis.granularity = 1;
xAxis.valueFormatter =self;
```

**#pragma mark - IAxisValueFormatter**

```
- (NSString * _Nonnull)stringForValue:(double)value axis:(ChartAxisBase * _Nullable)axis
{
    NSString *xAxisStringValue = @"";
    int myInt = (int)value;
    if(xVals.count > myInt)
    {
        xAxisStringValue = [xVals objectAtIndex:myInt];
        return xAxisStringValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```